# How to pin rows in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my Excel, I want to pin several rows.

You see the first three rows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifV6w.jpg)

when I scroll up, the first three rows will be hidden:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6cGi.png)

Is it possible to pin(let it in the fixed place) it, when scroll, it will still shows?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not looking to Freeze the Pane(Rows)? And if literally not,  VBA(Macro) can hide certain Rows to Scroll and Hide!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use Freeze Pane function, please select Row 4 and go to View- Freeze Panes- Select Freeze Panes:

[image]